# Select field from object in expression

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Within an `$addFields` stage of an aggregation pipeline, I'm trying to set the value of the field to one field from one subdocument (object) in an array.  I'm able to select the correct element of the array using `$arrayElemAt`, but I can't figure out how to pull out a single field from the selected document.  I suppose that I can add another stage to the pipeline, but I'd like to know if it's possible within the context of the expression.

Here's an example document: looks like this:

```
{ 
"category" : "Holidays", 
"titles" : [
    {
        "primary" : true, 
        "text" : "Holidays", 
        "lang" : "en"
    }, 
    {
        "primary" : true, 
        "text" : "חגים", 
        "lang" : "he"
    }, 
    {
        "text" : "מועדי ישראל", 
        "lang" : "he"
    }, 
    {
        "text" : "מועדים", 
        "lang" : "he"
    }
], 
"order" : NumberInt(10), 
"name" : "Holidays", 
"scheme" : "Tag Category"
}
```

I'd like to pull out the primary English title and primary Hebrew title as their own fields.  This is my `$addFields` stage:

```
{
"enTitle": { $arrayElemAt: [ {$filter: {
        input: "$titles",    
        cond: { $and: [
            {$eq: ["$$this.primary", true]},
            {$eq: ["$$this.lang", "en"]}
            ]
        }
    }}, 0]
    }
}
```

I'd like to pull the `text` field out of the selected document.